# Show specific columns with dataloader-sequelize in nested tables

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js, dataloader

Currently I have some models. I'm using graphql with dataloader-sequelize and it works fine as long as I show associated tables without third level.

My models:

**"articulo.js"**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Articulo = sequelize.define(
    'articulos', 
    {
      art_codigo: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      art_nombre: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      art_longitud: DataTypes.STRING(250),
      art_latitud: DataTypes.STRING(250),
      .....[more columns]
      art_contenido: DataTypes.TEXT,
    }, 
    {
      timestamps: false,    
      freezeTableName: true,
      name: {
        singular: 'Articulo',
        plural: 'Articulos',
      },
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ['art_codigo'],
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  Articulo.associate = (models) => {
    Articulo.belongsTo(models.canalizados, 
      {
          foreignKey: 'art_canalizado',
          as:"Canalizado",
      }
    );

    Articulo.belongsTo(
      models.articulos_tipos, 
      {
          foreignKey: 'art_tipo' 
      }
    );

  };
  return Articulo;
};
```

**articulo_tipo.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ArticuloTipo = sequelize.define('articulos_tipos', {
    ari_codigo: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true
        },
    ari_nombre: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    }, {
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true,
      name: {
        singular: 'ArticuloTipo',
        plural: 'ArticulosTipos',
      },
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ['ari_codigo'],
        },
      ],
    });

  ArticuloTipo.associate = (models) => {
    ArticuloTipo.hasMany(models.articulos)
  };

  return ArticuloTipo;
};
```

**canalizado.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Canalizado = sequelize.define('canalizados', {
    cnl_codigo: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true
        },
    cnl_fecha_alta: DataTypes.DATE,
    ...... [more columns]
    cnl_revisado: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    }, {
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true,
      name: {
        singular: 'Canalizado',
        plural: 'Canalizados',
      },
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ['cnl_codigo'],
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  Canalizado.associate = (models) => {    
    Canalizado.hasMany(models.articulos);

    Canalizado.belongsTo(
      models.canalizados_tipos, 
      {
          foreignKey: 'cnl_tipo',
      }
    );

  };

  return Canalizado;
};
```

**canalizado_tipo.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CanalizadoTipo = sequelize.define('canalizados_tipos', {
    cai_codigo: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true
        },
    cai_nombre: DataTypes.STRING(50)
    }, {
      timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: "canalizados_tipos",
      name: {
        singular: 'CanalizadoTipo',
        plural: 'CanalizadosTipo',
      },
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ['cai_codigo'],
        },
      ],
    });

  CanalizadoTipo.associate = (models) => {
    CanalizadoTipo.hasMany(models.canalizados) 
  };

  return CanalizadoTipo;
};
```

My resolvers:

**articulo.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const {detectarCampos} = require('../_extra/comunes'); //Optimize which columns you want to use in graphql
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const resolvers = {
    Articulo:{
        art_tipo: (parent, args, { models, options }, info) => {
           return parent.getArticuloTipo(options); //It's an internal getter from sequelize, isn't it?
        },
        art_canalizado: (parent, args, { models, options }, info) => {
            return parent.getCanalizado(options); //It's an internal getter from sequelize, isn't it?
        },
    },
    Query: {
        async getArticulo(root, { codigo }, { models }, info) {
            return models.articulos.findByPk(
                codigo,
                {attributes: detectarCampos(info),}
            );
        },
        async getArticulos(root, { nombre, tipo}, { models, options }, info) {
            var whereStatement = {};
            if(nombre){
                whereStatement.art_nombre = {[Op.like]: '%' + nombre + '%'};
            }
            if (tipo){
                whereStatement.art_tipo = tipo;
            }

            return models.articulos.findAll({
                attributes: detectarCampos(info),
                where: whereStatement,
                //limit: 10, 
                options
            });
        },
        async getAllArticulos(root, args, { models }, info) {
            return models.articulos.findAll( {
                attributes: detectarCampos(info),
                limit: 10, 
            });
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
    },
}

module.exports = resolvers
```

**canalizado.js**

```
const {detectarCampos} = require('../_extra/comunes');

const resolvers = {
    Canalizado:{
        cnl_tipo: (parent, args, { models, options }, info) => {
            return parent.getCanalizadoTipo(options)
        },
    },
    Query: {
        async getCanalizado(root, { codigo }, { models, context }, info) {
            return await models.canalizados.findByPk(codigo,
                {attributes: detectarCampos(info),});
        },
        async getCanalizados(root, { tipo }, { models, options }, info) {
            var whereStatement = {};
            if (tipo)
                whereStatement.cnl_tipo = tipo;

            return models.canalizados.findAll({
                attributes: detectarCampos(info),
                where: whereStatement,
                limit: 2, 
                options
            });
        },
        async getAllCanalizados(root, args, { models, options }) {
            return models.canalizados.findAll({
                attributes: detectarCampos(info),
                limit: 100, 
                options
            });
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
    },
}

module.exports = resolvers
```

It works fine if I search in graphql with this sentence:

```
query{
  getArticulos(tipo:2){
    art_codigo
    art_nombre
    art_tipo{
      ari_nombre
    }
    art_latitud
    art_longitud
  }
}
```

```
Executing (default): SELECT [art_codigo], [art_nombre], [art_tipo], [art_latitud], [art_longitud] FROM [articulos] AS [articulos] WHERE [articulos].[art_tipo] = 2;
Executing (default): SELECT [ari_codigo], [ari_nombre] FROM [articulos_tipos] AS [articulos_tipos] WHERE [articulos_tipos].[ari_codigo] IN (2);
```

On the other hand, if I try to look for in a deeper level, I get automatic names from columns I don't need to use:

```
query{
  getArticulos(tipo:2){
    art_codigo
    art_nombre
    art_tipo{
      ari_nombre
    }
    art_canalizado{
      cnl_codigo
    }
    art_latitud
    art_longitud
  }
}
```

```
Executing (default): SELECT [art_codigo], [art_nombre], [art_tipo], [art_latitud], [art_longitud] FROM [articulos] AS [articulos] WHERE [articulos].[art_tipo] = 2;
Executing (default): SELECT [ari_codigo], [ari_nombre] FROM [articulos_tipos] AS [articulos_tipos] WHERE [articulos_tipos].[ari_codigo] IN (2);
Executing (default): SELECT [cnl_codigo], [cnl_fecha_alta], [........], [cnl_revisado], [cnl_tipo], [cnl_fuente], [cnl_autor], [CanalizadoTipoCaiCodigo] FROM [canalizados] AS [canalizados] WHERE [canalizados].[cnl_codigo] IN (51357, 51365, 51379, [........], 63910);
```

In this case, in Graphql returns this error:
`"message": "Invalid column name 'CanalizadoTipoCaiCodigo'.",`

How can I ommite that field?? Could I use something like "attributes" to specify which attributes I'd like to show?? I tried to use it in resolvers, models... but always with no success

This error is the same if I look for a deep level:

```
query{
  getArticulos(relevancia:2){
    art_codigo
    art_nombre
    art_tipo{
      ari_nombre
    }
    art_canalizado{
      cnl_codigo
      cnl_tipo{
        cai_nombre
      }
    }
    art_latitud
    art_longitud
  }
}
```

Any idea about my problem? Everrything is wellcome!!

---

**UPDATE**

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = require('./configuracion/schema/typeDefs')
const resolvers = require('./configuracion/schema/resolvers')
const models = require('./configuracion/models')

const { createContext, EXPECTED_OPTIONS_KEY } = require('dataloader-sequelize');
const dataloaderContext = createContext(models.sequelize);

//const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, context: { models } });
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
    typeDefs, 
    resolvers, 
    context: async () => ({
      models,
      options: { [ EXPECTED_OPTIONS_KEY ]: dataloaderContext },
    }),
  });

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

models.sequelize.authenticate().then((err) => {
    console.log('*** MSG [server.js]: Successful Connection');
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('*** ERROR [server.js]: No ha sido posible conectarse a la base de datos', err);
})
//models.sequelize.sync();

app.listen({ port: 3000 }, () =>
    console.log(`** API ready at http://localhost:3000${server.graphqlPath} `)
);
```

**configuracion/models/index.js**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
//const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('../config_sqlserver')
const db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db_database, config.db_user, config.db_password, 
    {
        host: config.db_host,
        port: config.DB_PORT,  // <----------------The port number you copied
        dialect: "mssql",
        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000
        }
    }
);

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    //const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**resolver > articulo_tipo.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const {detectarCampos} = require('../_extra/comunes');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        async getArticuloTipo(root, { codigo }, { models, context }, info) {
            return await models.articulos_tipos.findByPk(codigo, { attributes: detectarCampos(info)},);
        },
        async getArticulosTipos(_, { nombre, tipo }, { models }, info) {r
            var whereStatement = {};
            if(nombre)
                whereStatement.ari_nombre = {[Op.like]: '%' + nombre + '%'};

            if(tipo)
                whereStatement.ari_codigo = tipo;

            return models.articulos_tipos.findAll({ 
                attributes: detectarCampos(info),
                where: whereStatement, 
            });
        },
        async getAllArticulosTipos(root, args, { models }) {
            return models.articulos_tipos.findAll()
        },
    },
    Mutation: {
    },
}

module.exports = resolvers
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use sequelize ... but I probably can point you in the right direction:

- attributes are used already...
- maybe not exactly the way you need ...
- check what is returned from `detectarCampos(info)` in resolvers

Probably you'll find that `info` is undefined ... sometimes `info` is missing... why!?

> ```
>     art_canalizado: (parent, args, { models, options }, info) => {
>         return parent.getCanalizado(options); //It's an internal getter from sequelize, isn't it?
>     },
> ```

`getCanalizado` is called with `options` while **normally** it should be called with **more arguments**:

```
    async getCanalizado(root, { codigo }, { models, context }, info) {
```

### Fix:

Pass missging arguments - it should work (if `detectarCampos` works, of course).

Comment: Yes, `detectarCampos`works :D. But certainly that `async getCanalizado(root, { codigo }, { models, context }, info) {` isn't called by `return parent.getCanalizado(options)`, because it's an internal getter which is created by sequelize automatically (I traced logs about it withoud success, so it´s true that it isn't called).

Comment: I'd log all result of `detectarCampos(info)` with call places ...
check relations: `Articulo.belongsTo(models.canalizados, ` vs `Articulo.belongsTo(models.articulos_tipos,`, why not `articulos_canalizados` ?  is `art_canalizado` in `canalizados` ?

Comment: `models.canalizados` is related with `articulos`, `news`, `events`... Each kind of those registers have their own  "canalizado", and `canalizado` has his own `canalizado_tipo`. That is my problem, return that last level `articulos>canalizados>canalizados_tipo`. I can show `articulos>articulos_tipos`, however I can´t jump until `articulos>canalizados_tipos` without `articulos>canalizados>canalizados_tipos` because the relationship is between `archivos` and `canalizados`. It`s really dificult to explain, isn't it?? xD

Comment: IMHO problem is earlier ... on `articulos>canalizados` ... from SQL even for `art_tipo` it returns all fields, not only required `ari_nombre` ... use `model.canalizados....` instead `parent.getCanalizado()`? ... still, log resolver called (method, params)

Comment: Yes, It'd be my second option, using `model.canalizados.findByPk(...)`, but it'd generate too many SQL sentences. I would like to use the cache system like dataloader to optimize my SQL sentences...if it was possible, of course.

Comment: if you return `cnl_codigo` it shouldn't affect SQL

Comment: I thought so, but when it uses `parent.getCanalizado(options)` from sequelize, it returns all my fields, and some more: `Executing (default): SELECT [cnl_codigo], [cnl_fecha_alta], [........], [cnl_revisado], [cnl_tipo], [cnl_fuente], [cnl_autor], [CanalizadoTipoCaiCodigo] FROM [canalizados] AS [canalizados] WHERE [canalizados].[cnl_codigo] IN (51357, 51365, 51379, [........], 63910);`

Comment: I saw that earlier, but this is overfetching, one of the problems graphql tries to resolve. Have you tried findbypk?

Comment: Yes, is works with `findByPk`. Pros: It works. Cons:if I find 100 elements, it'll execute 100 new SQL sentences. :) It's a pity, because most of them are the same SQL sentence, so it'd be perfect to optimize it.

Comment: dataloader is for that ?

Comment: With dataloader you can optimize how many times a nested table is called. `SELECT * FROM articulos_tipos WHERE ari_codigo IN (<id_1>, <id_2>....<id_n>)` vs n-querys 'SELECT * FROM articulos_tipos WHERE ari_codigo=<id_1>`. Sum up, Dataloader solves n+1 problem from Graphql

Comment: and what is in these 100 SQLs, how they are different?

Comment: In the worst case, as querys as diferents id's. The "big problem" is that most of querys are `SELECT * FROM canalizados_tipos WHERE cnl_tipo=1`, for example, and it's a pity send the same query again and again. So, finally, you have to send 100 extra querys to get a "type of register" when you'd only need... ¿1?¿2?

Comment: ... as above ... dataloader?

Comment: With dataloader only one query. Previously, It detect how many different "types of register" is going to show, and execute only query like `SELECT * FROM canalizados_tipos WHERE cai_tipo IN (<id_1>...<id_n>)` to get that info, instead of n-querys one by one, id by id.

Comment: More information in webs such as https://itnext.io/what-is-the-n-1-problem-in-graphql-dd4921cb3c1a or https://engineering.shopify.com/blogs/engineering/solving-the-n-1-problem-for-graphql-through-batching. It`s really dificult to explain with my poor english :) Sorry! By the way, thanks a lot for your time ;)

Comment: I know.... why you're not using this for this scenario - dataloader-sequelize - as in title ?

Comment: Well, I'm really using that powerful library. My problem is that It works fine to certain level. It fails if you go deeper. `articulos>articulos_tipos` is OK but `articulos>canalizados>canalizados_tipos` fails.

Comment: where exactly it's used... I don't see

Comment: Post updated with more information at the end. Better now? Certainly, think I didn't post enough information

Comment: dataloader context defined in graphql context - not used in sequelize `findByPK` ... not working at all beside main models? ... [new context should be created per [parent] request] ... not using `graphql-sqeuelize`? explore `dataloader-sequelize` issues for similiar examples